# using singular or plural after X versus Y

Tags: singular-vs-plural, grammaticality-in-context

I have a title like:

> Strong versus weak mode

I am not sure if I should use `mode` or `modes`?

Comment: Of course, you can dodge the question by lengthening the title: _Strong mode vs. weak mode_.

Comment: Depends whether you have one *mode* or *modes* on either side. Strong modes Vs. Weak Modes OR Strong mode Vs. Weak Mode OR Strong Vs. Weak modes OR Strong Vs. Weak Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "mode", because either side of the "vs" refers to a single mode and not a plural.